# Converting integer type to string rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using task model, which has 3 fields: `title:string`, `completed:boolean`, `priority:integer`

I want to transform integer values(1,2,3) to string values(Next,Now,Later) in priority.

I wrote to model:

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    PRIORITIES = [
        ['Later', 1],
        ['Next', 2],
        ['Now',3]
    ]
```

And also in form:

```
= f.input :priority, Task::PRIORITIES
```

Everything should work but I get an error:

`No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer in this line`

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you can do `f.select :priority, Task::PRIORITIES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [enums](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) for this, like this

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    enum priority: { later: 1, next: 2, now: 3}
 end
```

Comment: how should I change my form after this? It works, but I need a dropdown menu in my simple form

Comment: Ok, finally I did it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry I missed your first comment, I'm glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dropdown menu with an enum, you need something like this:

`<%= f.select :priority, Effort.priorities.keys.map { |priority| [priority.titleize, priority] }, {prompt: true}, {class: "dropdown-select-field"} %>`

As a bonus for using `enum`, you can call, for example:

`Task.low` on the class, or 
`task.next?` on an instance.